# Change css if bootstrap col are not horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap layout

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="upper"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="lower"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.upper {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.lower {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

if the screen is sm, the upper div will be ontop and the other below it. Each filling `100% width and height`. However, it'd like `upper` to only have a `80% height` if the screen is sm. Are there some way to work this out in bootstrap? Or some other smart way with jquery perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add xs class in each div after sm or you can do it with media query also

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
              <div class="upper"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <div class="lower"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.upper {
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
}

.lower {
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a responsive CSS media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .upper {
        height: 80%;
    }
}
```

This would sort of make sense with your existing CSS, as Bootstrap favors a mobile-first approach to development.  Your existing CSS rule for `.upper` would kick in for extra-small (xs) viewports only, and when the viewport is stretched out (to small/sm), this rule would overwrite your xs rule.